# Create remote powershell session in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, exchange-server

I'm very new to PS so I think I'm missing something basic here.  I can do a remote powershell session like this...

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange
                             -ConnectionUri https://remote.com/Powershell
                             -Credential "Domain\Admin"
```

I want the equivalent in C# so I'm trying this but it doesn't work...

```
WSManConnectionInfo connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
   new Uri("https://remote.com/Powershell"),    /* uri */
   "/wtf",                        /* shellUri??? */
   cred);                                       /* ps-credential */

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo))
{
    runspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.Runspace = runspace;
    }
}
```

This fails with...

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException was unhandled
  Message=Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The resource URI (/wsman) was not found in the WS-Management catalog....
```

How can I translate that into C#?  What is the "shellUri" parameter and how to I convey the configuration name (Microsoft.Exchange in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange

should work for shell uri and get context into the Exchange config

Comment: Oh I see, so specifying this "shell uri" in C# is equivalent setting the ConfigurationName to Microsoft.Exchange in Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

I use Something like

```
int iRemotePort = 5985;
string strShellURI = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
string strAppName = @"/wsman";
AuthenticationMechanism auth = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;

WSManConnectionInfo ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    false,
    sRemote,
    iRemotePort,
    strAppName,
    strShellURI,
    creds);
ci.AuthenticationMechanism = auth;

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
runspace.Open();

PowerShell psh = PowerShell.Create();
psh.Runspace = runspace;
```

With this you have access to remote powershell session.. Use psh to run commands remotely.

Answer (score -1):

The shellUri [should be http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff326159.aspx).