# Create Remote Powershell Session and load modules in Runspace using C#

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0, runspace

I want to connect to a remote powershell session and load modules in the runspace.

I got the connection part using this link :- 
[Create remote powershell session in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216594/create-remote-powershell-session-in-c)

How do I load the modules in the runspace and call other commands in that module ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd127644(v=vs.85).aspx) that accepts [an `InitialSessionState` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate(v=vs.85).aspx). An `InitialSessionState` object has a [`Modules` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate.modules(v=vs.85).aspx) which holds a collection of modules. You can add modules there and they'll be loaded when the runspace is opened.

Alternatively, you can just invoke `Import-Module` in the pipeline.